# Mapping Port Ranges of AWS Security Groups in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to iterate over a map of ports and port ranges to create an AWS Security Group in Terraform.  For Ingress ports, they give a `from_port` field and a `to_port` field.  This should define the range of ports for a specific rule in a Security Group.  I can do the mapping just fine when the rule is a single port, as both from and to port are the same.  But when the rule calls for a range of ports, I cannot figure out how to do this.  Here is the code that I have been testing with.  I think I have the right idea on how to do this but am running into type errors.

I am essentially trying to use the from_port's index value to find which port should map to the `to_port`.

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-east-2"
  profile = "default"
}

locals {
  start = [22, 33, 44] # from_ports
  end   = [25, 35, 45] # to_ports
  vpcid = "vpc-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "traffic_secgrp" {
  name        = "traffic_sec_grp"
  description = "Allows traffic"
  vpc_id      = local.vpcid

  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = local.start
    content {
      from_port   = ingress.value
      to_port     = element(local.end, [index(local.start, ingress.value)])
      protocol    = "UDP"
      cidr_blocks = ["10.2.0.0/20"]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the error I am getting from the `to_port` line:

```
Error: Invalid function argument

  on main.tf line 21, in resource "aws_security_group" "traffic_secgrp":
  21:       to_port     = element(local.end, [index(local.start, ingress.value)])
    |----------------
    | ingress.value is 44
    | local.start is tuple with 3 elements

Invalid value for "index" parameter: number required.
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my issue with the above code.  In the `to_port` line, I wrapped the index of the `element` function in brackets which caused the type issue.  Once I removed those brackets, it worked fine.

Working `to_port` line

```
to_port     = element(local.end, index(local.start, ingress.value))
```